# You are a sympathetic Cylon

Tags: battlestar-galactica, pegasus

I'm still pondering over our Cylon's greatest loss in the last 6 player game we played.
In turn 3 the first Cylon player got executed by an `Admiral Chooses` crisis card (Kain-player resolved that one true to character). Soon thereafter the 2nd Cylon revealed himself, turn 6 if I remember correctly, which was quickly followed by the Sleeper Agent phase.
 Now, what happens at this moment is that one of the Cylon players is dealt the `You are sympathetic Cylon` loyalty card. Which he, according to the rules must reveal immediately, and he becomes revealed Cylon. This seemed and felt a bit redundant, and quite a disadvantage for the Cylons.

From the base game rules:

> If a player receives a `You
>   are a Sympathizer` card, then he must immediately reveal
>   and resolve it. If he is a revealed Cylon player, then he may
>   first give the card to any other player (who then immediately
>   resolves it).

Pegasus rules instead say:

> When a human player receives this card (*`You are a Sympathetic Cylon`*) during the Sleeper phase, he must immediately reveal it. However, rather than following normal Sympathizer rules, this player becomes a revealed Cylon and draws an Agenda from the Sympathetic Agenda deck.

What I would like to know is if we interpreted the Pegasus rules correctly in the way that the part of the rule `rather than following normal Sympathizer rules` also affects passing on this card to another player as was done in the base game.

For those interested, Humans won with 4 fuel, 8 Food, 5 Morale and 9 Population, two civilian ships where destroyed while in space (`Blind Jump` by Kain), only one civilian ship was left behind on New Caprica. All the Raptors were accounted for and only one Viper was damaged. Only three Jumps were made to reach New Caprica.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A revealed Cylon player must always pass the *You are a Sympathizer* and *You are a Sympathetic Cylon* cards to another player. The Pegasus rule you quoted is for "when a **human** player receives" the card. See page 7 of the Pegasus rulebook:

> Sleeper Phase: When a Cylon player receives Loyalty Cards during
>   the Sleeper Agent phase, he looks at all of his facedown Loyalty
>   Cards and gives them to one human  player of his choice. **If the Cylon
>   player receives a “You Are Sympathizer” or a “You Are a Sympathetic
>   Cylon” card, he does not reveal it.  Instead, the human player he
>   passes it to must immediately  reveal this Loyalty Card as if it had
>   been dealt to him.**

So the original rule in the base game hasn't changed. It's just been expanded to include the *You are a Sympathetic Cylon* card.

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed that as I did not look in the correct place in the pegasus rulebook. gee.. it even has a big header named `Handing off Excess
Loyalty Cards`